# Passing Intent value through ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice

I have an android class and a Java class in same project.
I want to pass arraylist from android to java.

I am able to pass array, but not arraylist.
Could anyone please inform me about this ?

Android :

```
Intent i1= new Intent(context, WriteExcel.class);
i1.putExtra("stock_list", arrTransfer);
context.startService(i1);
```

Java File :

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    ArrayList<String> stock_list = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get("stock_list"); 
}
```

Here, in the Java File, if I arrayList to array, then i can get value.

Comment: you should override `onStartCommand` onstart is deprecated. You can pass a `ArrayList` as it implements serializable

Comment: @Raghunandan: can u explain or provide the code. i did not got you

Comment: deprecated means do not use the method. its no longer supported or recommended.

Comment: So, instead of onStart, i should use onStartCommand ?

Comment: yes that's what i point in the first comment. read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: read the doc and use `putCharSequenceArrayListExtra`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra to your Intent, like this :

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock", (ArrayList<String>) stock_list );
```

And retrieve it like this :

```
ArrayList<String> stock_list = data.getStringArrayListExtra("stock");
```

Comment: In retrieving I used, intent for data, and ur commands, but it crashed my app

Answer (score 0):

Try putStringArrayListExtra() instead:

```
Intent i1= new Intent(context, WriteExcel.class);
i1.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", arrTransfer);
context.startService(i1);
```

When you call startService(i1), android starts the activity WriteExcel (assuming you've done it correctly) by calling its onCreate() method and passing it the Intent. So this is where you should handle the Intent. Your onCreate() could look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> stock_list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("stock_list");
}
```

Comment: I cant use getIntent, as it is a Java Class

Comment: Updated my answer, try that instead. Also, all classes are written in Java.

Comment: I added a toast in oncreate and i see that that toast is not called in oncreate. And app crashes.

Comment: Updated the answer again, trying to clarify things a bit. If it still doesn't work, please post the code in the WriteExcel class.